# Powershell - Can't Get Emails Attachements

Tags: powershell, outlook, scripting, email-attachments, office-automation

I am trying to use powershell to read outlook inbox and get a certain mail with an attachement within. As slow as I am, I finally succeded in getting the proper mail, depending on the date and I only need to save the attachement.

That's where I am stuck at, I cannot for the life of my get the attachement. I've tried debugging with simple code to check random attachements, and I can't find any, I've tried checking everything around the test mail I sent myself with the attachement (and obviously verified that the attachement is available through outlook) and nothing does the trick.

Here is the code :

```
$OutlookObj = New-Object -comObject outlook.application
$OutlookNamespace = $OutlookObj.GetNamespace("MAPI")
#$OutlookFolder = $OutlookNamespace.PickFolder()
$olDefaultFolderInbox = 6
$OutlookFolder = $OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder($olDefaultFolderInbox)

$DownloadFilepath = "C:\Users\Me" 

$StringMatch = "Random"
$StringMatch2 = "Random"

# Dir to sav the attachements is made here 
$Downloaddir = Join-Path $DownloadFilepath "csv"
New-Item -ItemType Directory -force -Path $Downloaddir

$OutlookFolder.Items | ForEach-Object {
      $TodayDate = (Get-Date)
      $TodayDateStr = $TodayDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
      
      $TargetSubject = "Test mail - $StringMatch ($StringMatch2) for $TodayDateStr"
      if ((([DateTime]::Parse($_.ReceivedTime)).Date -eq $TodayDate.Date) -and ($_.Subject -eq $TargetSubject)) {
          $_.attachements
        }    
      }
  
$OutlookObj.Quit | Out-Null
[GC]::Collect()
```

Here's a one liner if you want to try it yourself

```
$OutlookFolder.Items | Select Subject, Attachements -Last 1 | Get-Member | Format-Table -Autosize
```

with its output for me :

```
   TypeName: Selected.System.__ComObject

Name         MemberType   Definition
----         ----------   ----------
Equals       Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method       type GetType()
ToString     Method       string ToString()
Attachements NoteProperty object Attachements=null
Subject      NoteProperty string Subject=
```

(I removed the Subject myself)

Here's a few leads I went for:

[Powershell to save email attachments within the last few days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40222408/powershell-to-save-email-attachments-within-the-last-few-days)
https://bronowski.it/blog/2020/09/saving-outlook-attachments-with-powershell/
https://blogit.create.pt/andresilva/2017/12/07/sending-an-email-with-attachments-using-outlook-and-powershell/

Now I have everything to save the attachement, I slowly believe that the security around the account is the thing that blocks my mail from being read, which would be weird since I do can read the body, the subject and I even make condition based on that. The attachement is the only thing that's missing.

I'm slowly think it's more of an organisation policy, more than my own fault in the code, but it would be weird that it gets up to the point where I have the content up to body but just not the attachement ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following `PowerShell script` to download the `Outlook` email attachment based on a condition being met.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

# Get the Inbox folder
$Namespace = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$InboxFolder = $Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) # 6 represents the Inbox folder
$Emails = $InboxFolder.Items
foreach ($Email in $Emails) {
    if ($Email.Attachments.Count -gt 0) {
        if ($Email.Subject -eq "RE: B2C  Custom Policy Trainings -Session 1") {          
            $Attachment = $Email.Attachments.Item(1) 
            $Attachment.SaveAsFile("C:\Folder11\Azure AD B2C Custom Policy -Day1.pptx")
            
            # Display email subject and sender information
            Write-Host "Email Subject: $($Email.Subject)"
            Write-Host "Sender: $($Email.SenderName)"
            break
        }
    }
}
```

The PowerShell code retrieves the emails in the Inbox folder, iterates through them, and checks if the email subject matches the desired criteria as per condition. If there is an attachment in the email, it saves the attachment to the specified location using the `SaveAsFile` method.

**Output:**

[image]

Refer: [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35883509/extracting-attachments-from-office-365) by Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Even if your code is working, it is very inefficient. Please don't copy wrong/improper answers.

Comment: Please let us know the requirements so that I can provide you with my best if the posted solution is not fulfil your requirement.

Comment: Posting without understanding how that works is not the best way to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Attachments` property of Outlook items to get the corresponding collection of attached files. Then you can access attachments using the `Item` method.

```
$Attachment = $Email.Attachments.Item(i) 
$Attachment.SaveAsFile(FilePathString)
```

The [Attachments.Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments.item) method returns an `Attachment` object from the collection. The [Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method saves the attachment to the specified path. A file path string which represents the location at which to save the attachment is passed as a parameter.

---

Also I've noticed that you iterate over all items in the folder and check the `Subject` and `ReceivedTime` properties of all items in the loop which is not correct:

```
$OutlookFolder.Items | ForEach-Object {
      $TodayDate = (Get-Date)
      $TodayDateStr = $TodayDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
      
      $TargetSubject = "Test mail - $StringMatch ($StringMatch2) for $TodayDateStr"
      if ((([DateTime]::Parse($_.ReceivedTime)).Date -eq $TodayDate.Date) -and ($_.Subject -eq $TargetSubject)) {
```

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the `Items` class that allow getting items that correspond to the search criteria, so you could iterate over items with attachments and subject line which corresponds to your criteria. DASL queries support the matching of prefixes, phrases, and substrings in a string property using content indexer keywords `ci_startswith` and `ci_phrasematch`, and the keyword `like`. So, you may use the following search criteria to get items with keywords in the `Subject` line:

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _ 
& "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) _ 
& " ci_phrasematch 'question'"
```

Also you can combine different search criteria into the single search string by using logical operators like `AND` or `OR`.

Finally, to search items with attachments you can use the following search criteria (VBA syntax):

```
query = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & Chr(34) & "=True"

'restrict the set to Emails that have attachments
items.Restrict (query)
```

In VBA, CHR is the VBA function and returns the character from the ASCII table. For example, `Chr(34)` returns the 34th character, which is the `"` sign.